# IIntelliJ Gradle sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Recently my organization has changed the jdk from Adopt to Adoptium.
Since then , my Intellij is not working.

Error:-

> Gradle sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe

1. I have changed the JDK version in settings -> Build -> Gradle -> Changed the version to `1.8.0_332`.
2. In JAVA_HOME (System Env Varaiable )= `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.332.9-hotspot\`
3. In CMD - Java Version is
   `openjdk version "1.8.0_332"`
   `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_332-b09)`
   `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)`

I have restarted my Intellij and machine multiple times. Still the error is not going away.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the same JDK on Windows 10. Can you test how it works from the command line? Does the `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe` path exist?

Comment: Make also sure that IDE has permission to execute this Java executable.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot` till here exits not the complete path. there is NO `JDK\bin\java.exe` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download gradle zip file from https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=7.0.2&format=all
   and unzip and keep it in a local path
2. settings -> Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle

`Gradle user home` -> choose the unzipped gradle (from step 1).

`Apply` and `OK`
3. Rebuild the Gradle.

This Worked For Me (and others who faced the same issue in our team)

[image]

Comment: Gradle user home - is the directory of the Gradle working directory. It is incorrect to set it to the Gradle directory installation. See the description at [Gradle user home](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home) Gradle documentation.

Comment: I downloaded the latest gradle zip file and put it in `C:/Users/orage/.gradle/wrapper/dists/` and unzipped it. then I choosed the same unzipped folder in `Gradle User Home` as shown in the screen shot. Actually that WORKED. I have no idea how.